# How do reset groupFirstKey QueueConfiguration field to default value (null) via ActiveMQServerControl.updateQueue(String queueConfiguration)

Tags: activemq-artemis

I created a queue via the method `ActiveMQServerControl.createQueue(String queueConfiguration)` with a value for the `groupFirstKey`.

How to reset `groupFirstKey` field of `QueueConfiguration` this queue to default value (null) via `ActiveMQServerControl.updateQueue(String queueConfiguration)`?

If I set `""` for `groupFirstKey` in the String queueConfiguration (for example `{"name":"MAXC","address":"MAXC","routing-type":"ANYCAST","group-first-key":""}`), then for the `groupFirstKey` value I get not `null`, but `""`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this via the management interface (i.e. using the `ActiveMQServerControl`) because `ActiveMQServerControl.updateQueue(String queueConfiguration)` ultimately performs a check on the members of the JSON input that is passed in, and any members that are `null` (i.e. don't exist) are *not* updated.

However, if you're using an *embedded* server then you can use the `updateQueue(QueueConfiguration, boolean)` method directly on `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQServer` and pass `true` for the `boolean` to *force* any `null` parameters to be used for the update.

Comment: But I can do it via a deprecated method `@Deprecated
String updateQueue(String name, String routingType, String filter, Integer maxConsumers, Boolean purgeOnNoConsumers, Boolean exclusive, Boolean groupRebalance, Integer groupBuckets, String groupFirstKey, Boolean nonDestructive, Integer consumersBeforeDispatch, Long delayBeforeDispatch, String user) throws Exception;` and using the current active method `updateQueue(String queueConfiguration)`, I cannot do this. Isn't this a issue?

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you think you've found a bug in ActiveMQ Artemis then you can open an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS) with a clear description of the issue and ideally a reproducer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Justin.  I will try a little later and write on the result.

Comment: I can't find a method `ActiveMQServerControl.updateQueue(String queueConfiguration, boolean force)` in `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ActiveMQServerControl`  https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.java (artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar). There is only the method `updateQueue(String queueConfiguration)` and 6 Deprecated updateQueue methods without queueConfiguration.

Comment: I see what's going on. I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: I also don't see what the deprecated method calls ultimately calls `updateQueue(String queueConfiguration)`. This method eventually calls `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl`  @Deprecated @Override public Queue updateQueue(String name, RoutingType routingType, String filterString, Integer maxConsumers, Boolean purgeOnNoConsumers, Boolean exclusive, Boolean groupRebalance, Integer groupBuckets, String groupFirstKey, Boolean nonDestructive, Integer consumersBeforeDispatch, Long delayBeforeDispatch, String user, Long ringSize) where the QueueConfiguration is created

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant to say was that I don't see how you could use one of the deprecated methods because they all eventually call `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl#updateQueue(org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.QueueConfiguration)` which is the same method you're calling directly.

Comment: In any event, if you really care about the fact that you can do this with one of the deprecated methods you should add those details to your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now everything is clear. Maybe in the future it is worth adding the possibility of calling the `updateQueue(QueueConfiguration, boolean)` method from `ActiveMQServerControl`

Comment: Feel free to open a feature request issue at [ActiveMQ Artemis Jira project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS) for anything you think would be worth adding.